# How to transform a sine wave to square wave (0 or 1) using Python?

Tags: python

I saw this diagram and wonder how can I transform a sine wave into a square wave using Python.  Which library will help me ?  How to implement "adaptiveThreshold" and "filterSignal"?  Please give me idea on where to look for?

[image]

Comment: iterate for each point of x and if the value at 0 or base put it y = base and if greater put 1 or max amplitude and less then base or 0 put it min/negative amplitude of base

Comment: Did you do any research, like, perhaps, searching for _python signal adaptive threshold_?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a quick example in python:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

num_cyc, n_samples = 10, 401
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi * num_cyc, n_samples)
y = np.sin(x)
y_ = np.convolve(y, np.ones(num_cyc*20)/(num_cyc*20), mode='same')

thres = 0.01
y_sq = [1 if n >= thres else -1 for n in y_]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(x, y, "-k")
plt.plot(x, y_, "--b")
plt.plot(x, y_sq, "-r")

plt.savefig("sine2step.jpg", dpi=300)
```

The code first generates a sine wave using numpy and then plots it using matplotlib. What you need for an adaptive threshold is a wide sliding window so that the resulting "adaptive threshold" averages values over multiple cycles (`y_`).

Then use that adaptive threshold (most often in combination of a threshold value `thres`) to check whether your original signal `y` is below or above `y_` and assign a value for the resulting step function `y_sq` accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code.  Really helpful.